# Replacing special sign with sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file and there is a part which I would like to replace with another one. The problem is that the new part contains special signs like `{=./}` and I'm not able to do that using sed.

What I want to do is to change `text123` into `{text123=./bla}`.

I tried to do it with `sed` command but look like there are some issues with that. Can any help me with?

Looks like I found a solution but unfortunately there is another problem. I want to put all line below (with all special signs) into text file using echo:

```
sed -i -e 's/Location/Location\n\n\/\/One_File\nPart Second File '"{ d =.\/source; }"'\nThird File '"{ d =.\/source; }"'/' $file
```

So once I run script it will take me something like this:

```
Location
\\One file
Part Second File { d =.\/source; }
Part Third File { d =.\/source; }
```

Can anyone help me with that? Seems there are too many special signs here, but I need them all.

Comment: What issues? Why doesn't `echo something_text123_something | sed 's,text123,{text123=./bla},g'` work?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo text123 | sed 's/text123/{text123=.\/bla}/g'
```

result :

```
{text123=./bla}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using back reference with `sed`:

```
echo text123 | sed 's/\(text123\)/{\1=.\/bla}/g'
{text123=./bla}
```

Comment: Looks like I found solution but unfortunately there is another one. I want to put all line below (with all special signs) into text file using echo:

**then sed -i -e 's/Location/Location\n\n\/\/One_File\nPart Second File '"{ d =.\/source; }"'\nThird File '"{ d =.\/source; }"'/' $file**

So once I run script it will take me something like this:

Location<br/>
\\One file<br/>
Part Second File { d =.\/source; }<br/>
Part Thrird File { d =.\/source; }<br/>

Can anyone help me with that? Seems there is too many special signs here but I need them all

Comment: @nemox007 Update your original post, since its not possible to see the formatting of your data in the comment. Also use the code tag button `{}` to mark data.